# Why is my gridline above x-axis and how can I correct it(matplotlib)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

In the figure (see the link below the code), you can see that the bottom horizontal gridline is above the x-axis whereas I would prefer it to be overlapping the x-axis to make the graph look more accurate. Could anyone please tell me how to achieve that? Also, it would be amazing if someone could tell me how I can start my graph from 0 at the bottom left corner. Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x_coordinates = np.array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
y_coordinates = np.array([0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40,45 ])
plt.xlabel("extension/mm")
plt.ylabel("tension/ N")
plt.title("extention vs tension correlation")
plt.xticks([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18])
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(b=True, which="minor", color="black" )
plt.grid(b=True, which ="major",color="black")
plt.plot(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

It's plotting the minor ticks, and that looks confusing against the x-axis. If your plot range ends on a major tick, then it will look nicer. Here is one possible solution:

```
plt.ylim([min(y_coordinates),max(y_coordinates)])
plt.xlim([min(x_coordinates),max(x_coordinates)])
```

Comment: You are an absolute genius my friend. Thank you so much!